# When using cider-find-var, how to make it jump to the definition on the original file instead of going to the output of lein install on maven folder?

Tags: clojure, find, ide, clojurescript, cider

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript **dynamic web app** project.

There is the main repository, let's call it **principal**. And also a supporting repository, called **supporting**.

Ok. On my local `~/projects` folder, I have `~/projects/principal/` and also `~/projects/supporting`.

At some point, after building the project being on `~/projects/principal/`, I am using the ClojureScript REPL to invoke a function from one of the dependencies, the supporting repository:

```lisp
cljs.user> (supporting.core/my-function my-variable)
```

With the cursor on top of `supporting.core/my-function` I execute the command `cider-find-var` (bounded to `M-.`) . This is a cool command. It allows me to jump to see the definition of the function!

The only problem is where CIDER is pointing me:

```bash
Directory /Users/pedro/.m2/repository/supporting/1.2.15/
```

As you can see, it **does not** point to the "original source code" of the supporting repo. It actually points to the "compiled version" related to Maven (the output of `lein install`, if my understanding is correct).

But, as far as I know, it is not appropriate to edit this. I need to edit the **original** file pre-compile on a different folder.

How to make CIDER jump to the original **editable** pre-compiled repository?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848059/can-you-have-leiningen-load-library-code-from-locally-checked-out-source ? E.g. put supporting under the checkouts of principal.  I can't say, what emacs, cider, shadow-cljs make out of it, but at least it allows for easy library development with leiningen.

Comment: Thank you, @cfrick. I have not tried this approach. I will try and them update my question (or post an answer, if it becomes a successful approach).