# How to improve the workflow of editing dependencies and watching the changes on a main Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project?

Tags: build, clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript **dynamic** web app project.

There is the main repository, let's call it `principal`. And also a supporting repository, let's call it `supporting`.

Ok. On my local `~/projects` folder, I have `~/projects/principal/` and also `~/projects/supporting`.

As the names suggest, `supporting` is a dependency of `principal`.

Currently, the workflow to work on both repositories *is extremely painful*. I would like to know if there is a better way.

This is the current workflow:

1 - Build the project on `principal` with: `cider-jack-in-cljs,` I choose `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and `app` for build option.

2 - If `principal` needs a tweak on the interfaces of `supporting`, it is **not** possible to edit `supporting` directly and **watch the changes** live.

3 - Thus, I copy the function to be tweaked on `supporting` and paste it on `principal`. Then, I tweak namespaces and some names. I do the tweak and adjust the invocation. More importantly, I am able to **watch** the changes on the live app being displayed on localhost.

4 - Everything seems to work fine after some tests.

5 - Now, it is time to edit things on `supporting` repository. This time, with the proper namespaces and names. Also, it is time to **remove** the temporary duplicate on `main`

6 - It is **not** possible to watch the changes on `supporting` **without** re-building the whole thing on `principal` **after** doing *a new* `lein install` on `supporting`.

7 - After a `lein install` on supporting, quitting `watch app` and re-doing the entire build of `principal`, I can see the app live and check if everything is fine.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848059/can-you-have-leiningen-load-library-code-from-locally-checked-out-source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as shadow-cljs is concerned it'll always watch files. The only rule is that it doesn't watch files in `.jar`, since those can't change. So, all you need is telling shadow-cljs where it can find the files.

You didn't specify how you are managing dependencies, so I'm going to assume you just have them in `shadow-cljs.edn` `:dependencies`.

One way to have `shadow-cljs` watch the `supporting` files is just adding the source paths directly.

```clj
{:source-paths ["src/main" "../supporting/src/main"]
 :dependencies [[your/supporting "0.1.0"]]
 :builds ...}
```

You keep the dependency as well, but by including the source path entry you ensure those files are used over the files in the installed `.jar`. You keep the declared `supporting` dependency so its dependencies are picked up properly.

Another option is using `lein` `checkouts` and managing dependencies in `project.clj`. `lein` can also use the trick above by adding source paths outside the project.

Another option is using `deps.edn` to manage dependencies and declaring the `supporting` dep via `:local/root`.

```clj
{:paths ["src/main"]
 :deps {your/supporting {:local/root "../supporting"}}}
```

Comment: Your advice really improved my workflow. I believe one of the reasons `shadow-cljs` is becoming really popular and trusted by the Clojure community is due to how helpful you are. Thanks, @ThomasHeller. And keep the good work!